# Add Dropdown list in App Part Properties

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have created **sharepoint hosted app**. I like to add dropdown list in app part properties which fetch data from list and bind it in dropdown. I've tried with static dropdown using enum but I want to create it dynamically.